# What is kthreadd_task

Tags: linux-kernel

In the definition of kthread_create a task is waken up, does any one know what is this task doing ?

```
struct task_struct *kthread_create

{


    struct kthread_create_info create;

    create.threadfn = threadfn;
    create.data = data;
    init_completion(&create.done);

    spin_lock(&kthread_create_lock);
    list_add_tail(&create.list, &kthread_create_list);
    spin_unlock(&kthread_create_lock);

    **wake_up_process(kthreadd_task);**
    wait_for_completion(&create.done);

    if (!IS_ERR(create.result)) {
            struct sched_param param = { .sched_priority = 0 };
            va_list args;

            va_start(args, namefmt);
            vsnprintf(create.result->comm, sizeof(create.result->comm),
                      namefmt, args);
            va_end(args);
            /*
             * root may have changed our (kthreadd's) priority or CPU mask.
             * The kernel thread should not inherit these properties.
             */
            sched_setscheduler_nocheck(create.result, SCHED_NORMAL, &param);
            set_cpus_allowed_ptr(create.result, cpu_all_mask);
    }
    return create.result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kthreadd_task` is pointer to `task_struct` of kernel thread runnind `kthreadd()` function defined at http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.36/kernel/kthread.c#L231

`kthreadd()` is main function (and main loop) of daemon `kthreadd` which is a *kernel thread daemon*, the parent of all other kernel threads.

So in the code quoted, there is a creation of request to kthreadd daemon. To fulfill this request kthreadd will read it and start a kernel thread. Then it will change the flag. In the code you have a waiting on this flag. After flag changing your function will check the status of new kthread creation.

Answer (score 4):

kthreadd is a kernel daemon,it is started during kernel boot.

```
init/main.c ---> kernel_thread(kthreadd,...)

(architecture dependent code for e.g arch/arm/kernel/process.c)
```

As you can see here, `kernel_thread()` returns a `pid`. From `pid` we determine the `task_struct` and assign it to `kthreadd_task`.

So whenever a call for creation of kernel thread i.e., `kthread_create()`, `kthreadd_task` is waken up, which inturn calls `kthreadd()` (defined in `kernel/kthread.c`).