# Reserved Process ID

Tags: linux, unix, pid, proc

As per my knowledge `Process ID 1` is reserved for `init`.

What does process id 2 indicate? why no softlink to the binary executable for this process ID.

```
sudo ls -l /proc/1/exe    
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 24 14:53 /proc/1/exe --> /sbin/init
```

But for /proc/2/exe

```
ls : cannot read symbolic link /proc/2/exe: No such file or directory
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 24 14:53 /proc/2/exe
```

Im using Ubuntu 12.04.

pls share your knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because at the moment you are asking there is no process of pid 2.
the kernel allocates pids at will.

Or because pid 2 is for some **kernel task**; on my machine it is for `kthreadd` which is some pure kernel process. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4167208/841108).

Comment: so whenever a process dies, corresponding folder also deleted in /proc right. But folder /proc/2 is available.

Comment: process of pid 2 could be a system process, not belonging to you. then `/proc/2/` exists but is not accessible *by you*

Comment: I guess, process 2 couble forked by process 1, so there is no binary exe link in that /proc/2/exe.

Answer (score 1):

It's because there is no binary to link to. This process was probably started by the kernel itself. Take a look at the out put of `ps aux`. Any process you see listed in brackets will not have a exe soft link either.